# UIWebView альтернативные способы перейти по ссылке

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Необходимо открывать страницу сервиса в `UIWebView`, где пользователь вводил бы свои данные и обрабатывать результат.

`url` такого вида (генерируется сервером, по нему производится оплата)

> https://test.paysecure.ru/pay/order.cfm?Merchant_ID=nnnnnn&OrderNumber=eennnnn&OrderAmount=503,5&OrderCurrency=RUB&Delay=1&FirstName=Rrrrrrr&LastName=Rrrrrrr&Email=eeeee@eeeee.ee&MobilePhone=+n
>   nnn nnn nn
>   nn&URL_RETURN={company_domain}/payment/assist/return&URL_RETURN_OK={company_domain}/payment/assist/111683/pass&URL_RETURN_NO={company_domain}/payment/assist/111683/fail

Вынужден заменить русские буквы на r, цифры на n, aнглийские буквы на e, домен своей компании на {company_domain} в целях безопасности, но соблюдая все пробелы и порядок.

Пытаюсь создать из этой строки `NSURL` для открытия страницы в `UIWebWiew`. Но в результате получаю `nil` и страница в `UIWebView` не открывается. Если открываю ссылку в браузере, то все ок и происходит пересылка на страницу платежа. следовательно инициализатору `NSURL` не нравится формат строки. Я подозреваю что дело в том, что `url` довольно сложный.

Каким образом можно обойти эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL сложный, нужна кодировка чтоб его можно было представить как адрес. Попробуйте так:

```
let url : NSString = "https://test.paysecure.ru/pay/order.cfm?Merchant_ID=nnnnnn&OrderNumber=eennnnn&OrderAmount=503,5&OrderCurrency=RUB&Delay=1&FirstName=Rrrrrrr&LastName=Rrrrrrr&Email=eeeee@eeeee.ee&MobilePhone=+n nnn nnn nn nn&URL_RETURN={company_domain}/payment/assist/return&URL_RETURN_OK={company_domain}/payment/assist/111683/pass&URL_RETURN_NO={company_domain}/payment/assist/111683/fail"
let urlStr : NSString = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
let urlToOpen : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(urlToOpen) //пробуйте в UIWebView
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало